# How do I know which activity is the next in the pile?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity Z to add some, you can come at this activity from two ways, first is from activity X, and the other is from activity Y(is a list of the data that you inserted in activity Z), how can I know if it was the activity X that called the activity Z so I can open the activity Y before closing the activity Z?

I could pass something like that zIntent.putExtra( "call", 0 ) //0 for Z calling and 1 for Y calling.

But is there any other way to do that? Like a method that tells you which activity is going to be the next in the pile?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the startActivityForResult method to start up Z. Once you are finished doing what you want to you can call finish with a result and it will return to X or Y, depending on which one called startActivityForResult.

More info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html